# How do I get the black notch to show in the screenshot when running iPhone X in simulator?

Tags: xcode

It appears I seem to be the only one with this issue as I don't see anyone with this issue on **SO**.

But how the heck do I get the black notch when using the iPhone X in the simulator to take a screenshot?

Here's what I'm running:

[image]

Yet when I take a screenshot, I get this:

[image]

I've even went to Edit->Copy Screen, yet the notch is still missing from the screenshot.

Where the heck is the black notch at? Is there a setting I need to turn on/off?...or is this normal?

I'm currently running **Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)**.

**NOTE:** I need to upload these screenshots to the App Store so they must contain the correct size dimensions.

Comment: I wonder if the App Store already displays the notch…?

Comment: @JonReid the App Store does not display the notch. I have an iPhone X device and searching for my app displays the screenshots as above. I did notice some apps show the notch but it was not the "actual" screenshot, but a screenshot taken as mentioned by answer below

Comment: Bummer, sounds like everyone is using a Photoshop template

Comment: I have the opposite issue, my simulator (10.2.1 / Xs Max) screenshot **contains** the notch area + round edges as **transparent** on the png. This makes it invalid for apple store, secondly, looks stupid, what should I do with the empty area?

Answer (score 6):

Yon can get it using the Terminal. With your simulator screen ready to be captured, just type:

```
$ xcrun simctl io booted screenshot --mask black screenshot_name
```

And you will get a screenshot with notch and with the required size.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press `Command` + `Shift` + `4`
2. Then press `Spacebar`
3. Click on simulator.

Comment: It should be Command + Shift + 5 instead, but it will take a screenshot of whole simulator container (as a program), including Title bar and Close, Minimize, and Maximize buttons.